# Hessian Web Calls using REST Client

Tags: rest, hessian

How to call a Hessian Server from the REST Client Google extension

This is my sample request

Request

> POST /RPCService HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: x-application/hessian
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_27
>
> Host: asvignesh.in:9000
>
> Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 27

c..m..getbloglist

How to Send Hessian Grammar c..m..getbloglist format as Key Value pair like Content-Type: Text/html